# Why Lord Krishna didn't change the Rule when delivering justice to the 16000 princess but married them Himself?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, dharma, marriage

- **16000** Princess were kidnapped by Narakasura and saved by Lord Krishna.
- If a young girl is **out of home for one day, no one will marry her**. It was a **rule** in that time and even nowadays.
- So Lord Krishna married 16000 princess*
- **Lord Krishna did adharma** (killing of Drona, Karna and Bhisma) to restore Dharma.
- In same way, Krishna could have **Changed that rule and allow to marry such women**

**DOUBT :**

- Why didn't Lord Krishna Change that rule and allow to marry such women instead of marrying them himself ?
- Is there any **Specific reason for changing the Rule** ?

Comment: This is a personal-opinion Q so will likely get closed. Let's say he changed the rule. Do you think everyone would have immediately changed and 16000 men would have come forward to marry them? Didn't Krishna himself have opposition in terms of Jarasandha, Poundraka vasudeva etc.? Was everyone abiding by Krishna's word back then? Besides, isn't it the girls' great fortune that Krishna himself married them instead of an ordinary mortal? Also,why do you think he did not change the rule? Isn't the changed rule seen in kaliyuga often?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar friend i unable to understand "So there was no need for Shree-Krishna to change the rule , cause they were pure and observing the vow of faithful wife (sati)" Are you saying that if they are impure Lord Krishna can change the rule. What is the relation between Pure and Impure to change of rules and marrying all of them ?

Comment: I didn't mean that.But you need to understand the fact that Shree-Krishna (though) god ,was king of Dwaraka only and not of entire Bharat-Varsha so even if he done that ,it could have been applicable to his kingdom only. Now all those women were of Divine nature and was keeping a vrata (which is not entirely clear from HVP) Secondly i haven't came across any scripture yet which says god changed so &so rule.So they being keeping vrata ,kept seprate and no mentioning of Narakasura touching them in any manner.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61768/discussion-on-question-by-sakthi-why-lord-krishna-didnt-change-the-rule-when-de).

Answer (score 3):

NOTE - Your question is not totally clear to me , but i am giving the explanation of Shree-Krishna marring 16,000 princesses here.

**`•    Why Lord Krishna Didn't Break the Rule to give Dharma to the 16000 princess ?`**

The answer of your question and the clarification of Shree-Krishna Marring 16,000 princesses at a time is given in Shreemad-Bhagvat purana. **SB 10.59: The Killing of the Demon Naraka.** [**SB 10.59**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/)

So From the story we know that shree-Krishna killed Narakasura / Bhaumāsura and librated 16,000 princess , whom  he abducted and kept in his palace. We also can see that , when all these princesses saw Shree-Krishna they got enchanted /attracted towards him and in mind assumed him as husband.

So it was the wish of all  the princesses to become wife  of  Shree-Krishna . Knowing their wish Shree-Krishna , Assuming each separate individual form for everyone of them , and then married them.

> तत्र रज्कन्यानां षटसहस्स्रधिकायुतम् | 
>  भौमाह्यतानां विक्रम्य
>   राजभ्यो ददृशे हरि: ||33||
>
> tatra rājanya-kanyānāṁ ṣaṭ-sahasrādhikāyutam
>  bhaumāhṛtānāṁ
>   vikramya rājabhyo dadṛśe hariḥ
>
> There Lord Kṛṣṇa saw sixteen thousand royal maidens, whom Bhauma had
>   taken by force from various kings.[**SB 10.59.33**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/33)
>
> ---
>
> तं प्रविष्ठं स्त्रियो विक्ष्य नरवीरं विमोहिता: |  
>  मनसा
>   वव्रिरेsष्टम पतिं दैवोपसादितम् ||34||
>
> tam praviṣṭaṁ striyo vīkṣya nara-varyaṁ vimohitāḥ 
>  manasā vavrire
>   ’bhīṣṭaṁ patiṁ daivopasāditam
>
> The women became enchanted when they saw that most excellent of males
>   enter. **In their minds they each accepted Him, who had been brought
>   there by destiny, as their chosen husband.**[**SB 10.59.34**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/34)
>
> ---
>
> भूयात् पतिरयं मह्यं धाता तदनुमोदताम् |
>  इति सर्वा: पृथक् कृष्णे
>   भावेन ह्यदयं दधु: ||
>
> bhūyāt patir ayaṁ mahyaṁ dhātā tad anumodatām
>  iti sarvāḥ pṛthak
>   kṛṣṇe bhāvena hṛdayaṁ dadhuḥ
>
> With the thought “May providence grant that this man become my
>   husband,” **each and every princess absorbed her heart in
>   contemplation of Kṛṣṇa.**[**SB 10.59.35**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/35)
>
> ---
>
> अथो मुहूर्त एकस्मिन् नानागरेषु ता: स्त्रिय: | 
>  यथोपयेमे
>   भगवांस्तावद्रुपधरोsव्यय: ||42||
>
> atho muhūrta ekasmin nānāgāreṣu tāḥ striyaḥ
>  yathopayeme bhagavān
>   tāvad-rūpa-dharo ’vyayaḥ
>
> Then the imperishable Supreme Personality, **assuming a separate form
>   for each bride,** duly married all the princesses simultaneously, each
>   in her own palace.[**SB 10.56.42**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59/42)

This is further confirmed in another chapter  no 69 canto 10

> चित्रं बतैतदेकेन वपुषा युगपत् पृथक् | 
>  गृह्येषु द्वयष्टसाहस्त्रं
>   स्त्रिय एक उदावहत ||2||
>
> citraṁ bataitad ekena vapuṣā yugapat pṛthak 
>  gṛheṣu
>   dvy-aṣṭa-sāhasraṁ striya eka udāvahat
>
> He thought, “**It is quite amazing that in a single body Lord Kṛṣṇa
>   simultaneously married sixteen thousand women, each in a separate
>   palace.”** [**SB 10.69.2**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/69/1-6)

Conclusion - So marring to all these 16 ,000 princes abducted by Narakasura , was **just one of the Leela’ of Shree Krishna. He assumed separate form  as a husband for each one of these 16,000 princesses , and married them and carried the Ghrustha-Ashrama separately with wach one of them.**

So he did not broke any rule , or nor by  this act  was done  Adharma by marring  all those 16,000 princesses .

---

**`Why didn't Lord Krishna Change that rule and allow to marry such women instead of marrying them himself ?`**

So the answer is provided by Harivamsha Purana. Where its said that those 16,000 women were Daughters of Gandharvas , and Seven different classes of Apsaras.
And some he also abducted some  women. So they were devine women.

They were kept in separate city called “Alaka” on Maniparvata. And they were observing Sati –Vrata.) (faithful wife) **So they were already pure** even staying at palace of Narakasura.

So there was no need for Shree-Krishna to change the rule , cause they were pure and **observing the vow of faithful wife (sati).**

> गन्धर्वाणां च या: कन्या जहार नरको बलि | 
>  याश्च्य देवमनुष्याणां
>   सप्त चाप्सरसां गणा: || HP 2.63.12 ||
>
> gandharvANAM cha yAH kanyA jahAra narako balI | 
>  yAshcha
>   devamanuShyANaM sapta chApsarasAM gaNAH  ||2-63-12||
>
> The Narkasura/Bhaumasura abducted many  girls of Gandharvas  , **some
>   of them also were daughters of human beings , and some of them were
>   from seven different classes of Apsaras**.
>
> ---
>
> चतुर्दश सहस्राणि एकविंशच्छतानि च | 
>  एकवेणीधरा: सर्वा:
>   सतिमार्गमनुव्रता: ||13||
>    chaturdasha sahasrANi
>   ekaviMshachChatAni cha | 
> ekaveNIdharAH sarvAH satImArgamanuvratAH
>   ||2-63-13
>
> They were fourteen thousand and twentyone hundred women in all. All
>   were with single plait of hair and **observing the vow of faithful
>   wife (sati).** [**HVP 2.63.12-13**](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_063.html)

Comment: friend  I am asking why didn't he broke the law as he did in kurukshetra but followed the law. Your answer is not answering my question

Comment: Ok . But where its written that - "Lord aksed the princess to go to thier Home. But they refused to go home because they Out of home for one day"I got confused about your question , so i will add a note in it.:)

Comment: friend it is in [ISCKON](https://news.iskcon.org/mp3/16000-wives-16000-krishnas,41/) and another question is if some women are absorbed in lord krishna then will he marry them all(AGAIN CONFUSION)

Comment: @Sakthi Not some of them, each and every one was absorbed in him.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Friend i am asking for example if some women(other womans) were absorbed or attractive to Lord Krishna will he marry them is it possible ?

Comment: @Sakthi No, Krishna probably wouldn't marry someone who didn't want to marry him.  But that's a moot point, because here all 16000 women did want to marry him.

Comment: I've always wondered about this ekavENi business. Even Sita is ekaveni during her stay in azOka vana. What does it mean?

Comment: @moonstar2001 -  Yes , even i haven't heard about it , may be it is related to keeping certain hair-style etc.or not combing hairs or not making knot.But it's just my guess.I will try to search more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Bro Shri Krishna had often accepted that many of those customs rules of that age were wrong n not wise...
But what could he do , if he had change those laws or rules do everyone accepted that  cause on earth he was just a king n not in form of God . He had taken birth in form of a human...
N that's why he had dreamed of Destructing the whole unwise n evil custom of that age n destroying the whole evil society n give rise to a new Era or new age of society with just n wise rules n laws by making happpen Mahabharata war  n that's why he made pandavas his weapon of destroying the whole evil society n giving rise to a new complete clean society with wise rules as he believed in yudhishthir n his empire will give a great justice full new empire .

N also Shri Krishna had not did adharma in killing Dronacharya n bhisma pita ..
In case of Bhishma pita he had not did any adharma as his death reason was shikhandi..
N in case of Dronacharya he had just tricked that too was not a false thing also... 
N also if he had did adharma on kurukshetra then he had explained that too ..
He explained that if the adharma by the evil reaches that level that you have to now end that evil n you can't do it in a Dharm full way but on other side the evil is constantly using adharma then you can make use of adharma (not adharma instead  tricky intelligent way )  in killing of that adharma .. n in this case that adharma did for wellbeing of Dharm ,it will be considered as Dharm n only this can be done in a very last step ...

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE thanks for answering friend but personal opinions can be posted in Comments and Answers should have scriptural lines. Online sriptures are available at large level so you can use them